# Transit visa through Portugal

Tags: transit-visas, portugal, morocco, ghanaian-citizens

Does a Ghana passport holder transiting through Lisbon Portugal en route to Morocco require an airport transit visa ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Ghanaian nationals are required to be in possession of an airport transit visa when passing through the international transit area of airports situated in any of the Schengen states https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/apply_for_a_visa_en